# Models to extract Causal Relationship between entities in a document using Natural Language Processing techniques

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, causation

I am looking to extract causal relations between entities like Drug and Adverse Effect in a document. Are there any proven NLP or AI techniques to handle the same.  Also are there ways to handle cases where the 2 entities may not necessarily co-occur in the same sentence.

Comment: Hi. Please, ask the question "Also are there ways to handle cases where the 2 entities may not necessarily co-occur in the same sentence." in another post. Ideally, one question per post.